# How do I recover from broken upgrade to KDE Plasma 5.27.2

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, login, kde

I wanted to us KDE Plasma on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, but I had problems as I discussed here
[Desktop "freezing" on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458083/desktop-freezing-on-kubuntu-22-04-lts)

As none of the suggested solutions worked, I switched from the KDE Plasma desktop to the Xfce desktop.  I've had no problems since the switch, so I'm pretty confident the problem is with Plasma.

I reported the Plasma problem as a bug here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=468340, but I was told that the version I was using (that ships with KDE 22.04 LTS) was too old to be eligible for support or maintenance.  It was suggested that I update to Plasma 5.27 to see if I experience the same bug in that version.

To upgrade to Plasma 5.27 I first needed to upgrade from Kubuntu 22.04 LTS to KDE 22.10, so I followed the instructions here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KineticUpgrades/Kubuntu.
This seemed to have worked fine as after the upgrade I could login using KDE Plasma as usual.

However, after upgrading from Plasma 5.25 to use Plasma 5.27 by following the instructions here https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-27-2-for-kubuntu-22-10-available-via-ppa,
that is,

```
add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
apt full-upgrade
```

I ended up without any option to use KDE Plasma as my desktop.  Here is an image of the desktop options I have a login:

[No login option for KDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPRdN.png)

How can I recover from this situation?  What can I do to log in using Plasma 5.27 (which is installed on my system)?